# Updating a structure in function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

We have created a structure hsv as defined below.

```
struct hsvoutput {
    float hue; // angle in degrees
    float saturation;
    float value;
};
```

and

```
struct hsvoutput hsv[img->x * img->y];
```

where the size is pulled from an image size.

```
int RGBtoH(int r, int g, int b, struct hsvoutput hsv, int i)
{

    float h;
    float s;
    float v;
    RGBtoHSV(r, g, b, &h, &s, &v);
    hsv.hue[i]= h;
    hsv.saturation[i] = s;
    hsv.value[i]= v;
    return h;
}
```

We would like a way to get the function RGBtoH to set the ith value of the hsv structure to the h, s and v values. This i value is the iteration value from a loop that calls this RGBtoH function.

However this error occurs when attempted as above.

> error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector

Comment: function should be int RGBtoH(int r, int g, int b, struct hsvoutput *p_hsv, int i);

Comment: and while calling function  RGBtoH() give structure addr

Comment: 'hsv' is an array, so this line: `int RGBtoH(int r, int g, int b, struct hsvoutput hsv, int i)`  should be: `int RGBtoH(int r, int g, int b, struct hsvoutput *hsv, int i)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your structure definition,

```
struct hsvoutput {
    float hue; // angle in degrees
    float saturation;
    float value;
};
```

`hue`, `saturation` and `value` are not of array type. You cannot use indexing on them.

So, later, writing

```
hsv.hue[i]= h;
hsv.saturation[i] = s;
hsv.value[i]= v;
```

is (are) wrong. They all are single variables and using indexing is invalid on them.

Solution: If you want to have the *array* `hsv` to be passed to your function, and update the values for the fields of all the elements, you should do something like (pseudo code)

```
int RGBtoH(int r, int g, int b, struct hsvoutput *hsv, int i)   
{                               //change hsv type to pointer

    float h;
    float s;
    float v;
    RGBtoHSV(r, g, b, &h, &s, &v);
    hsv[i].hue= h;                   //use indexing on hsv
    hsv[i].saturation = s;           //use indexing on hsv
    hsv[i].value= v;                 //use indexing on hsv
    return h;
}
```

Comment: Tried to upvote. I selected yours as the answer. Wont' let me upvote at the moment I am afraid.

Comment: @studentuser You'll be needing 15 points to upvote. Nevermind, if the solution (_any_) has helped you, marking that as accepted is the thing you should be doing (which you did). :-) At any later point, when you'll be having 15+, _if you feel_, you can come back and click the up-tick, but that's upto you. Cheers !!

Answer (score 1):

That should be:

```
hsv[i].hue = h;
...
```

and

```
int RGBtoH(int r, int g, int b, struct hsvoutput *hsv, int i)
```

The array in your case is hsv so that should be indexed like so. Then you can pass a pointer to a hsvoutput in your function.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to index the structure attributes like an array, however per structure they are just single instances, so you cannot index them like an array. You should allocate an array of structures and then pass the pointer to that array, this way you can access the ith element of the array. See the code below.

```
 int RGBtoH(int r, int g, int b, struct hsvoutput *hsv, int i)
    {

        float h;
        float s;
        float v;
        RGBtoHSV(r, g, b, &h, &s, &v);
        hsv[i].hue= h;
        hsv[i].saturation = s;
        hsv[i].value= v;
        return h;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since hsv is the array you should change the parameter to a pointer type and then do the indexing on the pointer and not the floats. Like this:

```
int RGBtoH(int r, int g, int b, struct hsvoutput *hsv /*pointer*/, int i)
{
    float h, s, v;
    RGBtoHSV(r, g, b, &h, &s, &v);
    hsv[i].hue= h; // index on hasv
    hsv[i].saturation = s;
    hsv[i].value = v;
    return h;
}
```